# rescale MODIS NDVI value- fill value and background value after clip study area

Tags: clip, modis, ndvi, fill, timesat

I want to use MODIS NDVI time series to extract phenological parameters using TIMESAT software.
I have question about data prepration, Is it alwaysd necessery to rescale NDVI data?
valid range in MODIS NVDVI is -2000 to 10000.
I have cliped NDVI images with my study area map and now I have NDVI images with background value 0. I think I must set background value to -3000, because zero is a valid value in NDVI data, and the fill value / no data value in modid NDVI is -3000.